# MIPS; getting the LSB of a hexadecimal value

Tags: hex, mips

I understand that there are a few questions already addressing this. However, my question varies in some sort. Suppose I have to get the LSB of a value (hexadecimal) stored in a register; for e.g;

If register $t0 contains the value 0xA4, I need to obtain and store the value 4

If register $t0 contains the value 0xBF, I need to obtain and store the value F

I understand that the bitwise `AND`operation works for decimal values. Could someone please provide some assistance as to how I go about getting the LSB?

Kind regards

Comment: You want $t0 AND 0x0F

Comment: "I understand that the bitwise ANDoperation works for decimal values." - ordinary CPUs don't deal with decimal. They deal in binary.

Comment: Thanks Eugen and Mat. Mat, that was very stupid on my behalf. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Terminology gripe: what you actually want based on your description is the Least Significant _Nibble_, not the Least Significant _Bit_ / _Byte_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily AND the number from which you want to extract the LSB itself like this:

0xA4 AND 0x0F

is same as (in binary)

10100100b AND 00001111

this basically means that only last four digits will be extracted from binary number and that is the LSB you want.

Answer (score 1):

All the binary operations works on general purpose registers along w/ masks which are merely pure numbers (regardless of their underlying basis repr)
Even though x86 isn't MIPS you should have something like this

```
and EAX, 0xF
```